# pyspark automation using cron job

Tags: apache-spark, cron, pyspark

I have a cron job which gets called every two minutes
The purpose of this job is to check for new request and trigger a spark job.
Cron job --> calls a shell script --> calls spark-submit

```
source /etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh
source /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
spark-submit  --executor-memory 2g --num-executors 1 --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 \
                                  --py-files <some egg files location>  \
                                  <python main script> \
                                  <configuration file> <Input Parameters>
```

When manually trigered , the script works fine but when triggered through cron it goes into a dead lock trying to get spark context.

Any body anyone have pointers for me on this ?

Comment: use `http://airbnb.io/projects/airflow/`, `cron` is unreliable

Comment: how did you configure the cron job ?

Comment: @MedAli :  i use crontab -e  , and then put in the statement */2 * * * * sh /path/script.sh

Comment: @KarolSudol : Thanks for the comment, i will definitely look at it  , but as of now i wont be in a situation to introduce a new component.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with kerbeos . The link has the answer 
[Click Here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_spark-component-guide/content/configuring-kerb.html)